# Bootstrap Tokenfields set dropdown width

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-ui

I am using Bootstraps Tokenfields and I've discovered that for some reason the width on my opened list is set to over 1000

[image]

```
<ul id="ui-id-1" tabindex="0" class="ui-menu ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-autocomplete ui-front" style="min-width: 98px; width: 510.656px; top: 994px; left: 281px; display: none;">
    <li class="ui-menu-item">
        <div id="ui-id-29" tabindex="-1" class="ui-menu-item-wrapper">red</div>
    </li><li class="ui-menu-item">
        <div id="ui-id-30" tabindex="-1" class="ui-menu-item-wrapper">blue</div>
    </li>
    <li class="ui-menu-item">
        <div id="ui-id-31" tabindex="-1" class="ui-menu-item-wrapper">green</div>
    </li>
    <li class="ui-menu-item">
        <div id="ui-id-32" tabindex="-1" class="ui-menu-item-wrapper">yellow</div>
    </li>
    <li class="ui-menu-item">
        <div id="ui-id-33" tabindex="-1" class="ui-menu-item-wrapper">violet</div>
    </li>
    <li class="ui-menu-item">
        <div id="ui-id-34" tabindex="-1" class="ui-menu-item-wrapper">brown</div>
    </li>
    <li class="ui-menu-item">
        <div id="ui-id-35" tabindex="-1" class="ui-menu-item-wrapper">purple</div>
    </li>
    <li class="ui-menu-item">
        <div id="ui-id-36" tabindex="-1" class="ui-menu-item-wrapper">black</div>
    </li>
    <li class="ui-menu-item">
        <div id="ui-id-37" tabindex="-1" class="ui-menu-item-wrapper">white</div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I have tried to set the css to width:100% but it just gets overwritten at runtime.

```
.ui-autocomplete {
    max-height: 200px !important;
    overflow-y: auto !important;
    /* prevent horizontal scrollbar */
    overflow-x: hidden;
    border:1px solid #222;
    position:absolute;
  }
```

I have tried to set the above css as well but nothing happens.

I also saw that I could try to set it via jquery but this didn't work as well

```
<script>
    $('#tokenfield').tokenfield({
        autocomplete: {
          source: ['red','blue','green','yellow','violet','brown','purple','black','white'],
          delay: 100
        },
        showAutocompleteOnFocus: true
    });
    jQuery.ui.autocomplete.prototype._resizeMenu = function () {
        var ul = this.menu.element;
        ul.outerWidth(this.element.outerWidth());
    }
</script>
```

Hope someone can take a look at this and see how I can configure this.

Comment: What version of jQ & Bootstrap are you using? Are you able to recreate this behavior in a jsFiddle/CodePen/etc? There's likely some CSS elsewhere on your page that's getting applied to your `li.ui-menu-item` elements - trying to isolate that would help. You can also use the Inspector pane in the Dev Tools of your preferred browser, then check the 'Computed' tab to see where where/how the width property is being set.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
el.tokenfield({
    autocomplete: {
        source: data,
        minLength: minLength,
        delay: delay,
        open: function (event, ui) {

            // make width of dropdown equals to width of input field
            var _openDD = $("ul.ui-autocomplete.ui-widget-content:visible");
            var _width = $(this).parent().width();

            _openDD.width(_width);
        }
    },
    delimiter: c_delimiter
});
```

Comment: While this may answer the question it's better to add some description on how this answer may help to solve the issue. Please read [How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) to know more.